# ActionBar appears when i press on Edittext and when i finish typing and close the keyboard it is still there

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fullscreen

Is there anyway to permanently remove this actionbar? I tried these two ways but they didn't work:

this ..

```
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

and this ...

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
              View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

First activity:
[image]

When i click on EditText:
[image]

[image: When i close the keyboard:]

Comment: Where is the Action bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the `ActionBar` it is called the `Status bar` in android. Because it persists the status of some important utilities like your network and battery status.

Coming to your question.

> FOR Android 4.0 and Lower

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

> FOR Android 4.1 and Higher

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
//if you have action bar present make sure to hide it
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```